# Resources for symbols or for making custom symbols?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, data-driven-pages, telecom

I am currently working on a data driven pages project to auto export maps of cell tower coverage. The current base Esri symbology is lacking in the telecom field so I am wondering if anyone knows any outside resources to search and download symbology based on discipline.

For example, for my maps I want to setup data driven symbology for the feature to automatically rotate based on the azimuth of the cell radio. If you have ever seen the RF tool "Atoll", that program does something like that natively and I want to mimic the symbology within that as close as I can. Here is a sample image. [image: Example image]

If out of the box symbology packs are not super common, any resources out there that demonstrate how to make custom symbols would be great.

Comment: in ArcMap there is a Marker Editor (the issue is you need to use geodatabase 'Representation') https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/working-with-the-marker-editor.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Telecom Symbol Fonts](https://community.esri.com/t5/telecommunications-questions/telecom-symbol-fonts/td-p/303746) at the Esri Community suggests that Telecom symbology is being extended by Esri:

> Esri's been developing a new symbol set for use with a data model in
> the utility network. Some of those symbols are available with the
> early preview of the data model here:
> https://community.esri.com/t5/telecommunications-questions/communications-utility-network-foundation-esri/td-p/138117

Comment: Although these are some great symbols they are more outside plant and distribution related. What I am looking for is something more "RF" related for the planning and research phase of what kind of radio and antenna is being used at the cell site.